# How to modify a method of a class where this class inherits in at least 2 levels?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, pandas

Pandas package offers DataFrame.to_html() method. This method takes data in a tabular format and displays it as html table.

I would like to modify the behavior of this method. However, I don't want to change the source  code of the package, I would like to extend it.

To clarify this, I would like to keep method DataFrame.to_html() intact and create a new method DataFrame.to_html2().

The problem here is that, the behavior of this method is defined in another method of a class which is an indirect superclass of of DataFrame.

This is the structure:

class DataFrame

method to_html # This method is called in my script

instance of a class DataFrameFormatter # This instance is initiated inside method to_html

PLEASE IGNORE THE INDENTATION ISSUE WITH CLASS AND DEF:

```
class DataFrame(NDFrame):

    @Appender(fmt.docstring_to_string, indents=1)
def to_html(self, buf=None, columns=None, col_space=None, colSpace=None,
            header=True, index=True, na_rep='NaN', formatters=None,
            float_format=None, sparsify=None, index_names=True,
            justify=None, force_unicode=None, bold_rows=True,
            classes=None, escape=True):
    """
    to_html-specific options

    bold_rows : boolean, default True
        Make the row labels bold in the output
    classes : str or list or tuple, default None
        CSS class(es) to apply to the resulting html table
    escape : boolean, default True
        Convert the characters <, >, and & to HTML-safe sequences.

    Render a DataFrame as an HTML table.
    """

    import warnings
    if force_unicode is not None:  # pragma: no cover
        warnings.warn("force_unicode is deprecated, it will have no "
                      "effect", FutureWarning)

    if colSpace is not None:  # pragma: no cover
        warnings.warn("colSpace is deprecated, use col_space",
                      FutureWarning)
        col_space = colSpace

    formatter = fmt.DataFrameFormatter(self, buf=buf, columns=columns,
                                       col_space=col_space, na_rep=na_rep,
                                       formatters=formatters,
                                       float_format=float_format,
                                       sparsify=sparsify,
                                       justify=justify,
                                       index_names=index_names,
                                       header=header, index=index,
                                       bold_rows=bold_rows,
                                       escape=escape)
    formatter.to_html(classes=classes)

    if buf is None:
        return formatter.buf.getvalue()
```

class DataFrameFormatter

method to_html of class DataFrameFormatter

instance of a class HTMLFormatter # This instance is initiated inside method to_html

```
class DataFrameFormatter(TableFormatter):

def to_html(self, classes=None):
    """
    Render a DataFrame to a html table.
    """
    html_renderer = HTMLFormatter(self, classes=classes)
    if hasattr(self.buf, 'write'):
        html_renderer.write_result(self.buf)
    elif isinstance(self.buf, basestring):
        with open(self.buf, 'w') as f:
            html_renderer.write_result(f)
    else:
        raise TypeError('buf is not a file name and it has no write '
                        ' method')

def _get_formatted_column_labels(self):
    from pandas.core.index import _sparsify

    def is_numeric_dtype(dtype):
        return issubclass(dtype.type, np.number)

    if isinstance(self.columns, MultiIndex):
        fmt_columns = self.columns.format(sparsify=False, adjoin=False)
        fmt_columns = zip(*fmt_columns)
        dtypes = self.frame.dtypes.values
        need_leadsp = dict(zip(fmt_columns, map(is_numeric_dtype, dtypes)))
        str_columns = zip(*[[' ' + y
                            if y not in self.formatters and need_leadsp[x]
                            else y for y in x]
                            for x in fmt_columns])
        if self.sparsify:
            str_columns = _sparsify(str_columns)

        str_columns = [list(x) for x in zip(*str_columns)]
    else:
        fmt_columns = self.columns.format()
        dtypes = self.frame.dtypes
        need_leadsp = dict(zip(fmt_columns, map(is_numeric_dtype, dtypes)))
        str_columns = [[' ' + x
                        if not self._get_formatter(i) and need_leadsp[x]
                        else x]
                       for i, (col, x) in
                       enumerate(zip(self.columns, fmt_columns))]

    if self.show_index_names and self.has_index_names:
        for x in str_columns:
            x.append('')

    return str_columns
```

class HTMLFormatter

method write_td # This is the method which i have to modify

```
class HTMLFormatter(TableFormatter):

indent_delta = 2

def __init__(self, formatter, classes=None):
    self.fmt = formatter
    self.classes = classes

    self.frame = self.fmt.frame
    self.columns = formatter.columns
    self.elements = []
    self.bold_rows = self.fmt.kwds.get('bold_rows', False)
    self.escape = self.fmt.kwds.get('escape', True)

def write(self, s, indent=0):
    rs = com.pprint_thing(s)
    self.elements.append(' ' * indent + rs)

def write_th(self, s, indent=0, tags=None):
    if (self.fmt.col_space is not None
            and self.fmt.col_space > 0):
        tags = (tags or "")
        tags += 'style="min-width: %s;"' % self.fmt.col_space

    return self._write_cell(s, kind='th', indent=indent, tags=tags)

def write_td(self, s, indent=0, tags=None):
    return self._write_cell(s, kind='td', indent=indent, tags=tags)
```

The question is about - how to handle this problem?

I was thinking of creating second version of each class involved, and modify this part of the code which is responsible for initiating instances.

Is this the most efficient way of handling this?

Comment: might be easier to understand if you put some code here

Comment: indentation is wrong: class definitions should be indented, but this is not the core issue in this question, so please ignore it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `pandas.core.format.HTMLFormatter` class to your own class when call `to_html2`:

```
import pandas as pd
import functools

class HTMLFormatter2(pd.core.format.HTMLFormatter):
    def write_th(self, s, indent=0, tags=None):
        super(HTMLFormatter2, self).write_th(s.upper(), indent, tags)

def replace_html_formatter(func, formatter):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped_f(*args, **kw):
        try:
            old, pd.core.format.HTMLFormatter = pd.core.format.HTMLFormatter, formatter
            return func(*args, **kw)
        finally:
            pd.core.format.HTMLFormatter = old
    return wrapped_f

pd.DataFrame.to_html2 = replace_html_formatter(pd.DataFrame.to_html, HTMLFormatter2)

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], columns=["a", "b", "c"])
print df.to_html2()
```

Comment: This is awesome. Can you please explain how replace_html_formatter works? Especially, this part: @functools.wraps(func)?

Comment: You can delete `@functools.wraps(func)`, it just copy some information such as docstring from func to wrapped_f.